# How does Vegeta new transformation name translates to English?

Tags: dragon-ball-super, japanese-language, dragon-ball-manga

I've seen over half a dozen names for Vegeta's new transformation in English. The Japanese name is 我儘【わがまま】の極意【ごくい】 (*Wagamama no Gokui*) but in English people calls it Ultra Ego, Mega Instinct, Instinct of Conquest, Superior obstination, etc.

How does Vegeta's new transformation name translate to English?

Answer (score 2):

Literally it means "Essence of selfishness".

- 我儘 = selfishness
- の='s/the thing before it possesses the thing after it,
- 極意 = essence/essential point/main point

Comment: Literally translations don't work well and yours is a bit off, especially the gouki bit. The translation for chapter 75 calls it Ultra Ego. This article offers a break down of the translation: https://comicbook.com/anime/news/dragon-ball-super-vegeta-ultra-ego-translation/

Answer (score 1):

Probably it is worth mentioning 我儘の極意, considered as a combination of ordinary words, makes little sense. As such anything may be fine as a translation as long as it vaguely reminds of the original, so I guess Ultra Ego is good enough.

The naming seems to be a kind of wordplay.

Apparently, Goku's new transformation uses a word 身勝手, which means *selfishness*. But the author takes it as 身(body) + 勝手 (as in 勝手に=instinctively, automatically), so the intended meaning is like *body moves instinctively*.

Now 我儘 also means *selfishness*, and that seems to be the reason of the word choice. Again, the author's intention is breaking it down as 我(I) + 儘(as) = *as I wish/want*. (This may be not too far from the original meaning anyway.)

極意 means something like *ultimate technique*. For example, *to get 極意 of X* in Japanese means a complete mastery of X.

Thus a bit awkward translation of 我儘の極意 is *the ultimate art of moving as I wish*.